# How to find out the amount of memory pyspark has from iPython interface?

Tags: memory, configuration, apache-spark, pyspark

I launched with the command

```
IPYTHON=1 MASTER=local[4] pyspark
```

Spark greets me with

```
Welcome to spark, version 1.2.1
SparkContext availabel as sc.
```

But using sc, I am not able to find the memory it has. How to find this out, and if possible how to set it to another value as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can query the configuration of the SparkContext like so:

```
sc._conf.get('spark.executor.memory')
```

or, if you're interested in the driver's memory:

```
sc._conf.get('spark.driver.memory')
```

The complete configuration can be viewed as a list of tuples by

```
sc._conf.getAll()
```